# Одностраничный HTML без обновления, JS и сервер на Java

Tags: javascript, java

Есть мини java-сервер, есть одностраничный интерфейс примерно следующего типа (тестовый). Необходимо создать скрипт такого вида, который позволяет отправить GET запрос, получить данные от Java-HTTP сервера и вставить данные в теги **table.innerHTML** .

Как выполнить отправку и получение GET - запроса **без** перезапуска страницы, с минимальными зависимостями? Желательно, даже без JQuery, на голом JS, но литература показывает, что без AJAX такие финты весьма проблематичны ...

Просьба: установку отдельного HTTP - сервера не рекомендовать, условия ТЗ не позволяют.

Примерный код интерфейса:

```js
<script>

function SetBackGround(sender)
{

    var cells = sender.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    
    for(i=0;i<td.length;i++)
    {
        td[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    }
          
    cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#dddeee";
    cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#dddeee";
    cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#dddeee";
    
    var s1 = document.getElementById('s1');
    var s2 = document.getElementById('s2');
    var s3 = document.getElementById('s3');
    
    
    s1.value = cells[0].textContent;
    s2.value = cells[1].textContent;
    s3.value = cells[2].textContent;
    
    fetch('127.0.0.1:8080/22').then(function(response) 
 { 
  response.text().then(function(text) 
  { 
   s3.value = text; 
  }); 
 });
 
    //cells[0].innerText = str;
    //cells[1].innerHTML = "<a href='http://ya.ru'>" + str + "</a>";

}
```

```css
<style>table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  align: center;
}

.child {
  height: 80;
  display: inline-block;
  align: center;
  width: 60%;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%
}

.box div {
  display: inline-block
}

.td {
  height: 100%;
}

.b1 {
  width: 60%;
}

.b2 {
  width: 30%;
  align: right;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">


    <div class="b1">
      <table width="100%" id="common">
        <tr onclick="SetBackGround(this)">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="SetBackGround(this)">
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="SetBackGround(this)">
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="SetBackGround(this)">
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="SetBackGround(this)">
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="SetBackGround(this)">
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>



    <div class="b2">
      Section1 : <br>
      <input type="text" id="s1" value="s3"> <br> Section2 : <br>
      <input type="text" id="s2" value="s3"> <br> Section3 : <br>
      <input type="text" id="s3" value="s3"> <br> <br>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

> Unexpected token <",
>     "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
>     "lineno": 106,
>     "colno": 9
>   }

Comment: Так у вас есть HTTP сервер или нету? Посмотрите в сторону `fetch` для отправки **GET** запросов.

Comment: Есть, обрабатывает через com.sun.net.http. Как это делать через fetch? И как мне впоследствии обрабатывать POST-запросы, когда мне нужно будет скидывать большой объём данных?

Comment: Гуглите https://www.google.com/search?q=fetch. Смотрите примеры. Простейший пример отправки запроса `fetch('http://...')`.

Comment: Если условия позволяют использовать JS, можно использовать XHR.

Comment: fetch('127.0.0.1:8080/22').then(function(response) {
        response.text().then(function(text) {
        s3.value = text;
        });
        });   - не отрабатывает. Сервер с классом хендлера на 127.0.0.1:8080 и возвратом "/answer" код не принимает. Где я ошибся?

Comment: Как для этой ситуации использовать XHR?

Comment: `XHR` и `fetch` по сути одно и то же. Принципиальных отличий между ними нет. Покажите ошибку, которая происходит при использовании `fetch`. Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Также добавьте в вопрос `js` код, как и где вы вызывали `fetch`.

Comment: Текст взят по проверке с ресурса. При обычном запуске с консоли перестаёт работать весь скрипт (примерно с fetch() ), ошибки не отображаются.